# docker-compose working but docker run not

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` with just one image. This is the `docker-compose.yml` definition:

```
services:
    myNodeApp:
        image: "1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myNodeApp:latest"
        container_name: 'myNodeApp'
        volumes:
        - data:/root/data
```

But I want to move it to `docker run` as I am using just one container. Executing a docker run command as the following:

```
docker run 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myNodeApp:latest --name myNodeApp -v "data:/root/data"
```

But I get this message `1.12.4`. However, executing `docker-compose up` starts the application and shows the log by output.

What is the difference? What is the equivalent of docker-compose up with docker? What am I doing differently?

Comment: What does `docker ps -a` gives you when having both the `docker run` and `docker-compose up`? That might be because of the project name prefixed when using compose.

Comment: try adding either `-d` or `-it` to your run command.

Comment: Docker-specific options like `--name` or `-v` need to come _before_ the image name in `docker run`; otherwise they get interpreted as the command to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this?

```
docker run -it --name myNodeApp -v "data:/root/data"
  1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myNodeApp:latest
```

Or maybe this command would help you, because it will build a local image associated with the config in your `docker-compose.yml` .

```
docker-compose build
docker images
```